# Getting dependencies between assemblies programatically by NDepend APIs

Tags: c#, .net, ndepend

I want to create an analyzer tool for extracting a dependency matrix like the matrix in Visual NDepend.

How do I list the dependencies that exist between two assemblies in a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read first the [NDepend.API Getting Started page](http://www.ndepend.com/API/webframe.html?NDepend.API_gettingstarted.html). Then, you can exercise by looking at CQLinq queries generated by right-click a non-empty dependency matrix cell *> Generate a query that matches these X code elements* ... For example, if the matrix option *Weight on cells* is set to *Direct: # methods*, you get:

[image: NDepend Dependency Matrixk]

... this generates the following CQLinq query. You can then reuse this query as a classic LINQ query in a program consuming *NDepend.API*. These generated queries should constitute a good starting point to develop more sophisticated dependency queries and programs.

```
from m in Assemblies.WithNameIn( "mscorlib").ChildMethods()
where m.IsUsedBy ("pnunit-launcher")
select new { m, m.NbLinesOfCode }
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
// 52 methods of the assembly
// mscorlib
// v4.0.0.0
// 
// are used by
// 24 methods of the assembly
// pnunit-launcher
// v1.0.4661.29691
//
```

Btw, here is the query edited view:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It was perfect for me!